# Filtering of port 3306 and opening only in times of need - The ultimate defence from DB hacking? (question had major update)

Tags: databases

I am not from the IS field and want to ask: Can we conclude that filtering of port 3306 and unfiltering only in times of need is the ultimate defense from DB hacking?

Let's assume I unfilter the port for 2-3 hours total in one year, just to make some DB changes ([say, with Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), or in a bit less secured way, PHPmyadmin) and then filter it again for some long months.

In my case for example, I can't use an IP whitelist (mainly because of travelling restrictions), hence it seems as the best solution I have at the moment.

Can we say that as long as the port 3306 (or a substitute port) is filtered, I am fully protected from BFAs or from SQL injections on the DB (given the Firewall has no breaches) unless someone brakes into the PC itself and doing changed from there ?

### Update - I seem to have had a flaw in the question:

The original phrasing of he question is above and some answer deal with it, but it seems I confused both the ongoing DB access via port 3306, with **interntal** access from PHPmyadmin (PMA), as well the issue of BFAs, with the issue of SQL injections.

I will emphasis the issue of BFA below:

I know see that even if I would filter the port with CSF **and never unfilter it afterwards** - Than from one hand, I would still be exposed to port knocking (which is a case by itself), and from the other hand, would still be able to use PMA from the URL, something that I could secure in either of the following 2 ways (or a combination of them):

1. Installing and uninstalling PMA each time anew, in an automatic way with a script that contains uninstall timeout, after 2 hours.
2. Logging in to PMA under https (tls).

Comment: If you only need access to it that infrequently, keep it on a standalone machine which isn't connected to the internet. Otherwise, you'll need some connection method open, even if it's a local socket for a web application to read data from. In that case, an attacker could just attack the web application to get access to the db

Comment: I am not sure I understand, you mean that if I will indeed keep the DB on the same machine of the Webapp but close port 3306, an attacker could destroy it indirectly after attacking it from the application?

Comment: SQL injections occur using the app that uses the database, and not via a direct database connection.

Comment: @schroeder, Yes. Now I can fully see why it won't protect from injections (read more on it), but what about BFAs alone?

Comment: Still not protected - you would need some way to enable access, and that would be vulnerable to brute force.

Comment: This is essentially a more manual version of [port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking?wprov=sfla1) that also (perhaps, it's unclear) opens the port for *everyone* during that time.

Comment: Why can't you use a whitelist? Can you use a whitelist for the short period you have it open?

Comment: @Matthew, I can't see how access of 2 hours each 6 months (for example), would be enough for BFAs... I really can't. Maybe because I am new to this and not an hacker.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov, I can't use a whitelist in case I'm travelling through countries and doesn't have a unique IP.

Comment: @Benia but you could add your current IP to the whitelist when you do your update

Comment: @benia How would you intend to unlock the system? Presumably through ssh or some web interface? Can someone brute force that interface, then enable the db access? In most cases, a web interface would be vulnerable, but ssh might be OK, if you're using certificate based auth. In that case, though, you could whitelist to your current IP address, which would be far better than a fully open service.

Comment: I would login to PMA with SSH each time, if that's what you mean by unblock... I will read on how to do so; How to encrypt each connection of PMA with SSH.

Comment: Why not connect to it from local host?

Comment: If I install PMA I work only from localhost AFAIK...

Comment: You are all welcome to visit: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146578/how-could-i-tunnel-all-actions-done-in-vps-from-my-browser-like-phpmyadmin/146588#146588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary defence in database management is setting up strong database authentication. Your connection to the database must be encrypted (e.g. SSH, TLS, VPN) and the database should authenticate you with a strong password and preferably with a client certificate.

The peripheral database defence is to protect access using VPN, Firewall, IP whitelisting.

Whether you use Workbench or PHPMyAdmin has little to do with securing access to your database. Both can be configured for strong security, and both can screw you up.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Should I choose between SSH, TLS or VPN? Or should I use 2 or all 3 together? What is most common for most users with small business websites, I wonder?

Comment: @Benia: Either [SSH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-ssh.html) or [TLS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connections.html) should be used as a minimum on smaller sites. VPN are usually used when you have multiple machines and you don't want to secure each machine individually, or as a secondary layer on enterprise installations. Yes, you can use all three at the same time, it might be necessary or overkill depending on your security requirements. You need to take care that the database does not expose its unencrypted port anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**: Absolutely not.

It takes less than 3 hours for someone to completely destroy your Database. I'll say that again - **your idea in its current form is a terrible practice, and is NOT a substitute for input sanitization**

~~Even if you'd said "We'll put the DB behind a firewall and whitelist IPs, it might have been a better idea.~~ - I see you updated your post, and can't do this.

Here are a couple of reasons why I feel this is not viable:

**Scenario**: I'm a nasty person watching your network for any sort of weakness. I'm very, *very* patient.

What happens: You mention that you are unable to use an IP whitelist. This means that I can now attack your server in a multitude of ways and not worry about having to spoof my location. How would I do it?

- Set up a script to scan your site every, say hour - just try to resolve /phpmyadmin and watch if it resolves. If it does, I begin my intelligent bruteforce. Not very clean and very noisy, but hey - it almost always works.
- None of your current solutions will prevent me from actually breaking your site in daily operations - SQL injection isn't only performed on one page - it'll work anywhere in your site where you haven't bothered to sanitize your inputs and are calling or pushing data to your DB. I'll start methodically attacking each of these areas throughout the year.

This should give you a pretty good idea why this isn't viable.

**2nd tl;dr**: Don't do it.

Comment: I don't have knowledge to understand how can someone destroy the DB if the port is filtered, besides entering through another port like 80 or 443. Sorry if it sounds funny to you, I am not of the field...

Comment: @Benia : How about this as a simple example: In those 2 hours, I find a fault, inject some nasty SQL. maybe `DROP TABLES *`? See how this could go south fast? 

Whatever you decide, always sanitize inputs. Always. Your solution is *not* a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I can now fully see why my solution isn't good at all for injections. But let's assume, theoretically that I am covered in another way from injections; What about BFAs alone?

Comment: One small note, the only user-managed inputs I have in all of my sites are simple contact-forms. Yet, I will see how sanitize them.

Comment: @Benia : Awesome! Good luck!

Comment: I have mended my ways. You are welcome to check this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146578/how-could-i-tunnel-all-actions-done-in-vps-from-my-browser-like-phpmyadmin